# A guide to learn data analysis

Tags: dataset, clustering, books

I'm new to data analysis and I need to do a data analysis project using clustering methods for a course in R. I have no idea how to start and choose my data set. I'm looking for some resources. Is there any book that teach data analysis with some real data set example that can help me figuring out how to start?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand that starting a data analysis project can be daunting, especially if you're new to the field. Choosing the right dataset and selecting the appropriate clustering method are crucial steps in ensuring the success of your project.

To help you get started, I recommend exploring online resources such as:

[Data Analysis Using Excel and Power BI](https://imanagementpro.com/en/course/data-analysis-using-excel-and-power-bi/)

[Data Analysis & AI Application in Excel & Power BI Diploma](https://imanagementpro.com/en/course/data-analysis-course/)